# How to select records from 2 tables with different but conditional fields?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one holds tv shows "general" information and the other one holds episodes/seasons. I need to be able to show all records from the "general" information table but with some data from the "episodes" table.

Table 1 (tvshows) structure:

```
id (int) | showname (varchar) | showcategory
```

Table 2 (episodes) structure:

```
id (int) | tvshow (int) | episode (int) | season (int) | year(int) | poster(varchar)
```

Example:

tvshows:

```
1|The Big Bang Theory|150
2|Two and a half men|150
3|The Nanny|130
```

episodes:

```
1|1|1|1|2000|file1.jpg (The big bang theory, episode 1, season 1, year 2000)
2|1|1|2|2001|file2.jpg (The big bang theory, episode 1, season 2, year 2001)
3|2|5|4|2008|file3.jpg (Two and a half men, episode 5, season 4, year 2008)
4|2|6|4|2008|file4.jpg (Two and a half men, episode 6, season 4, year 2008)
5|3|1|1|1990|file5.jpg (The Nanny, episode 1, season 1, year 1990)
```

Now, I need to query based on the category, and get the tv show data, as well a some data from the episodes table. Ideally it would be:

If `category==150` the result would be:

```
The big bang theory (tvshows.showname) | 2 (count episodes.season) | 2000 (min episodes.year) | 2001 (max episodes.year) | file1.jpg (first poster found on episodes for this show)
Two and a half men (tvshows.showname) | 1 (count episodes.season) | 2008 (min episodes.year) | 2008 (max episodes.year) | file3.jpg (first poster found on episodes for this show)
```

As you can see, they are ordered by tvshows.showname.

If `category==130` the result would be:

```
The Nanny (tvshows.showname) | 1 (count episodes.season) | 1990 (min episodes.year) | 1990 (max episodes.year) | file5.jpg (first poster found on episodes for this show)
```

Now, I managed to do so by doing multiple queries, but since we're talking about HUGE tables (it's a IMDB style website) it takes over 2 minutes just to show some results, that's why I'm trying to optimize the query.

Comment: one of the first steps in optimizing a query is getting the output of EXPLAIN to see the execution plan, verify that MySQL is using the indexes we expect to be used. But without the table definitions (including storage engine, indexes (including uniqueness constraints), column nullability, ... and without the actual SQL text of the queries in question ... we can offer some general guidelines, and make some guesses (missing indexes?) but we're just guessing ...  ( confusingly, the question seems to reference `==` as a comparison operator, which is not valid in mysql)

Comment: id field on both tables is unique and auto-increment. that's the index. the tables are huge, including more fields, that's why I chose to show a simplified version (actual tables have nearly 40 fields)

Comment: perhaps covering indexes (for the queries) would improve performance... unless the queries are doing a lazy `SELECT *` and pulling *every* column.  a primary key on `id` is not going to be of any benefit for a query with a predicate `category = 150`. (confusingly, the table definition provided shows a column named `showcategory` but no column named `category`. Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html   (we still haven't a clue if the tables are using MyISAM or InnoDB or other storage engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a inner join

```
  select tvshows.showname
    , count( distinct episodes.season)
    , min(episodes.year)
    , max(episodes.year)
    , min(episodes.filename)
  from tvshows 
  inner  join episodes on tvshows.id = episodes.twshows_id 
  where tvshows.category=150 
  group by  tvshows.showname
```

be sure you have a proper composite index  on

table  tvshows  columns(category, id  )

and

table  episodes column twshows_id

Comment: You are a genius! It worked perfectly and lowered the load time from ~120 seconds, to 15 seconds!

Comment: @FabioCalderon.. Thanks  .. anyway  15 seconds   seems to much  to me ..  are you sure you have added  the two indexes  as suggested ??

Comment: Yes, both indexes are there... however we're talking about ~300k records, so 15 seconds between the query, doing some processing and generating a json file isn't that much :) I forgot to mention that the 15 seconds isn't just the query.